# angular table with dynamic column names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

Is it possible to populate a table with angular.js without defining the column names prior to the 'ng-repeat'? For example this is how I'm currently populating the table..

```
                     <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Arup Mnemonic</th>
                            <th>Organism</th>
                            <th>Test</th>
                            <th>Result</th>
                            <th>Source</th>
                            <th>Source Value</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
                            <td>{{ x.Arup_Mnemonic }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.organism }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.test }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.result }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.source }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.source_value }}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Is it possible to remove all the hard coding and have the scope variable determine the column names along with and data ?

Quick Edit:
[image]
heres a quick look at the data in its current state.. I need the key in the key:value elements of this object. Is there a way to get those values with pure javascript ?

Comment: Why not: `<thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>` ?

Comment: Sure, just define the columns' names in the controller in the same way as `data`.

Comment: thanks thats a good idea, please check out the edit @Vidul

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you don't know what the columns are beforehand. So, you need the keys of the first object to understand what the columns are.

angular:

```
var obj = data[0];
$scope.columns =  Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof key == 'string') {
    return key;
  }
});

$scope.format = function(str) {
    return str.replace('_',' '); //do the rest of the formatting here. 
}
```

html:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        {{format(column)}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="datum in data">
      <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        {{datum[column]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: Took the filter on the keys from another answer as good practice when getting keys from objects.

Comment: Where does `obj` come from?

Comment: yes, I get the 'obj is not defined' error just as @Vidul pointed out.. I've tried hacking it with data and other variables but this example doesn't work

Comment: very true, forgot I was working with data[0]. Edited

Comment: @NickNasirpour When you copy & paste, at least try to fix my errors the next time.

Comment: @Vidul, I took the time to credit your answer... It's widely acknowledged that you should use hasOwnProperty and ensure that the key is a string. You probably copy-pasted from elsewhere as well.

Comment: @Nodedeveloper101 I noticed you may also need to stylistically format, which I'll edit my answer to accommodate right now.

Comment: @NickNasirpour Then how come you admitted the same logical mistake after me and fixed it after me? Please don't demonstrate the golden rule that impudence and incompetence go so tight to each other.

Comment: Only one person fully answered the question here. I don't know why you're so upset it wasn't you?

Comment: @NickNasirpour It's an ugly behaviour on your side. At least learn some JS (not just copycat tricks).

Comment: Are you serious? To imply that there's no sort of collaboration and cooperation in programming is ridiculous and imbecile. I even credited your answer, which I was under no obligation to do, as a gesture of good faith. Once again, I'm sorry if I've somehow upset you. I'm done with this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a own model for your headlines to iterate through it?

Let `headlines` be an array, holding up all possible headlines, one for each index.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>           
    <tr ng-repeat="headline in headlines"> 
      <th>{{ headline }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>{{ x.Arup_Mnemonic }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.organism }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.test }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.result }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.source }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.source_value }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is the same idea as @Vidul, but how do I get the headline variable ?

Comment: Literally the same way as you've done with your `data` object. Simply define a object in your `$scope`, in this case it may be `$scope.headlines = { YOUR DATA HERE }`. At this rate you could have an array, holding up all possible headlines. In this case you would simply do `headline in headlines` and populate your `<th>`element with `{{ headline }}`. I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (please note that this is not tested):

```
// in controller
$scope.headlines = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof key == 'string') {
        return key;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <tr data-ng-repeat="(key,val) in gridData">
                                <th></th>
                                <th data-ng-repeat="col in columns" data-ng-init="CurrKey = col.key">{{val[CurrKey]}}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
```